# Asking User to input date in sql giving ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER Error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to input a date value from the user and then using that value in the query.

```
 select * from  TB_MNP_GTY_TRANS_STEPS where CREATE_DATETIME>=&startdate
```

Now when i run the sql statement in Toad and input 8/1/2012 as date data type i am getting

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Can someone suggest where i am wrong.Note that CREATE_DATETIME is of Date Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really specify what date format you are using in your parameter:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TB_MNP_GTY_TRANS_STEPS 
 where CREATE_DATETIME >= TO_DATE(&startdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Read about date formats [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Currently your session is expecting the date to be in its default NLS_DATE default fomat and obviously the format of the date you're entering is different.
Explicitly specifying date formats prevents this issue from occurring.

Hope it helps...

**EDIT:**
If you want to pass in the 8th January 2012 then you could specify your variable value as:

```
08/01/2012
```

And your select would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TB_MNP_GTY_TRANS_STEPS 
 where CREATE_DATETIME >= TO_DATE(&startdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Depending upon your environment you might need to wrap the variable in single quotes (for TOAD you definiely will) i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TB_MNP_GTY_TRANS_STEPS 
 where CREATE_DATETIME >= TO_DATE('&startdate', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

The error you are getting is caused by the format of the date string you are entering not matching EXACTLY the format you are specifying (see the leading "`0`" before the `8` and `1` in the day and month!)

Comment: now i am getting ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected error.

Comment: Are you using a correct date format for the date string you are trying to pass in? I'll amend my answer to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Date  casting necessary

```
select * from  TB_MNP_GTY_TRANS_STEPS where CREATE_DATETIME>=to_date(&startdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

and while passing parameter you should pass value in quoets as '08-09-1999'